# How to add Filtered by in FilterBar?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to implement the `FilterBar`. When clicked on *Hide Filter Bar*, I want to display *Filtered by(): Filter name1, Filter 2, Filter 3*. Something like the below screenshot:

[image]

But I want to do it using `FilterBar` control.

Also, when I add some data to the Filters, I'm not getting the numbers of `filters()` used on the filter bar. 
Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GetFiltersWithValue`.

```
onInit(){
...
   this.oFilterBar = this.byId("filterbarID);
   this.oFilterBar.registerGetFiltersWithValues(this.fGetFiltersWithValues);
...
}
....
fGetFiltersWithValues: function() {
    var i;
    var oControl;
    var aFilters = this.getFilterGroupItems();

    var aFiltersWithValue = [];
    for (i = 0; i < aFilters.length; i++) {
        oControl = this.determineControlByFilterItem(aFilters[i]);
        if (oControl && oControl.getValue && oControl.getValue()) {
            aFiltersWithValue.push(aFilters[i]);
        }
    }
    return aFiltersWithValue;
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added this to my controller already but it's not working.
In my XML, I've defined "MultiComboBox" and "ComboBox" in my Filterbar under filterItems. When I enter data in the ComboBox fields, it is showing in filters(), but when i enter in MultiComboBox fields, it is not reflecting in the filters().

Comment: You have to adjust the code to work with your controls. This code is a sample and it's work with Input Control